# jQuery - show/hide div in interval with different timings

Tags: jquery, hide, setinterval, show

I have this two div's and want to show and hide div `.one` and `.two` alternately.

I want to show div `.one` for 10 seconds, hide it and show div `.two` for 5 seconds in a intervall.

I can only use classes because i have multiple `.one` and `.two` classes which all have to change with the jQuery-Code.

HTML:

```
<div class="one">show div 10 seconds</div>
<div class="two">show div 5 seconds</div>
```

jQuery:

```
setInterval("$('.one, .two').toggle();",2000);
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c9ncnof3/) here

Is it possible to do that? i tried to use `.delay` but that doesn't work with `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InitialFlip();

function InitialFlip() {
    setTimeout(SecondFlip, 10000);
}

function SecondFlip() {
    $(".one, .two").toggle();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".one, .two").toggle();
        InitialFlip();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: toggle is depreciated. i will not work in latest version of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```js
 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //initially hide second h1
        $(".two").hide();
    
        function show_second(){
            $(".one").hide();
            $(".two").show();
            setTimeout(show_first,10000);
        }
    
    
        function show_first(){
            $(".one").show();
            $(".two").hide();
            setTimeout(show_second,5000);
        }
    
        setTimeout(show_second,10000);
    });
```

```css
.one {
    background:green;
}
.two {
    display: none;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div class="one">show div 10 seconds</div>
    <div class="two">show div 5 seconds</div>
```

Comment: having problems with the timings. they don't match 10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5 ..
it gives 10, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10 ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var elems = ['.one', '.two'], delays = [1000, 500];
var curr = 0, prev = 0;
function showDiv() {
    $(elems[prev]).hide();
    $(elems[curr]).show().clearQueue().delay(delays[curr]).queue(function() {
        showDiv();
    });
    prev = curr;
    curr += 1;
    curr = curr % elems.length;
}
showDiv();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. This doesn't work with multiple .one and .two classes